# Dropdown textbox & button in the same row next to each other - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need dropdown, textbox1 , textbox2 and a button o be in the same row next to each other.
From reading other related questions, I have come up with the below.

```
.input-group-glue {
  width: 0;
  display: table-cell;
}

.input-group-glue + .form-control {
  border-left: none;
}
<div class="input-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Codes
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">A</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">S</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">N</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  <span class="input-group-glue"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" />
  <span class="input-group-glue"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" />
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="New Section" />
</div>
```

But the alignment is not there.
New to bootstrap, any direction would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

your alignment problem is because of `.form-control` and its `float:left` property try adding this:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
  float: left;
}
```

use with caution, it might throw off other dropdown buttons you have but will fix your alignment problem.

```css
.input-group-glue {
  width: 0;
  display: table-cell;
}

.input-group-glue + .form-control {
  border-left: none;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Codes
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">A</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">S</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">N</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  <span class="input-group-glue"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" />
  <span class="input-group-glue"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" />
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="New Section" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however even now when I add the last button, it misaligns.